# How many compositions of n with k parts are there where no part is divisible by 3?

Tags: combinatorics

This is what I am struggling on. Any help will be appreciated.

Let $n, k \in \mathbb N$. How many compositions of $n$ with $k$ parts are there where no part is divisible by $3$?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem and can share what you have tried so responders don't rehash things you know? Also, if this is HW, it should be tagged as such. Regards

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** There is a bijection between each composition with no part divisible by 3, and a way to obtain $x^n$ as a term in the expansion

$$ \left( x + x^2 + x^4 + x^5 + x^7 + x^8 + \ldots \right) ^k $$